# power point corrupted using officer

Tags: r, officer

I am using officer to make a ppt and i am using following code to insert a table in one of the slide. All is working fine. Though In the table, I need to do conditional text coloring, which works fine, if I do it multiple times. But when I use a for loop with in a function, codes works fine, but my ppt gets corrupted and I dont see the output in ppt. Any idea

```
library(data.table)
library(RMySQL)
library(officer) #from source
library(magrittr)
library(flextable)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)

tmrank.ft <- regulartable(data = tm.rank.out) %>% 
    theme_booktabs() %>% 
    autofit() %>%
    merge_v(j=missing_species) %>%
    align(align = 'center') %>%
    align(align = 'center', part = 'header') %>% 
    bold(part = 'header') %>%
    height(height = 1, part = 'header') %>% 
    fontsize(size = 14, part = 'all') %>% 
    width(j=1, width = 1.0 ) %>%
    width(j=2:ncol(tm.rank.out), width = 2.5) %>%
    (
      function(x) {
        ## These for loop causes the issue. If I dont use for loop, it works great.
        for (ii in 2:length(species)) {
          group_result <- group_vector( tm.rank.out.temp, grp.type, 'human')
          if(length(group_result) >0) {
            for (jj in 1:length(group_result)) {
              text_color <- grp.clr[names(group_result)[jj]]
              color(x, i = group_result[[jj]], j = ~ human, color = text_color) 
              }
           }
         }
       }
     )
```

Data is like

```
dput(head(tm.rank.out))
```

> structure(list(rank = 1:6, human = c("AoEC (2.1)", "LSEC (2.1)", 
>   "LMVEC (2)", "Prostate (2)", "Trans Lymphocytes (2)", "Thyroid (2)"
>   ), cyno = c("AoEC (2.2)", "DR Ganglion (2.2)", "Kidney (2.2)", 
>   "LMVEC (2.2)", "Retina (2.2)", "Gallbladder (2.1)"), dog = c("DR Ganglion (2.6)", 
>   "Striatum (2.6)", "Bone Marrow (2.5)", "NAc (2.5)", "Adrenal (2.5)", 
>   "Cecum (2.5)")), sorted = "rank", class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
>   ), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = )

```
dput(head(tm.rank.out.temp))
```

> structure(list(rank = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), human = c("AoEC", 
>   "LSEC", "LMVEC", "Prostate", "Trans Lymphocytes", "Thyroid"), 
>       cyno = c("AoEC", "DR Ganglion", "Kidney", "LMVEC", "Retina", 
>       "Gallbladder"), dog = c("DR Ganglion", "Striatum", "Bone Marrow", 
>       "NAc", "Adrenal", "Cecum")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
>   ), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = )

Comment: Please include all other non-base packages you are using (perhaps `magrittr` or `dplyr`?) and a sample of data in a format we can easily use (e.g., output from `dput(head(tm.rank.out))`).

Comment: This is hard to help there, what is `missing_species`, `species`, `group_vector`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out, I had to put "x" in the end loop of the function. so it would be like

```
tmrank.ft <- regulartable(data = tm.rank.out) %>% 
theme_booktabs() %>% 
autofit() %>%
merge_v(j=missing_species) %>%
align(align = 'center') %>%
align(align = 'center', part = 'header') %>% 
bold(part = 'header') %>%
height(height = 1, part = 'header') %>% 
fontsize(size = 14, part = 'all') %>% 
width(j=1, width = 1.0 ) %>%
width(j=2:ncol(tm.rank.out), width = 2.5) %>%
(
  function(x) {
    ## These for loop causes the issue. If I dont use for loop, it works great.
    for (ii in 2:length(species)) {
      group_result <- group_vector( tm.rank.out.temp, grp.type, 'human')
      if(length(group_result) >0) {
        for (jj in 1:length(group_result)) {
          text_color <- grp.clr[names(group_result)[jj]]
          color(x, i = group_result[[jj]], j = ~ human, color = text_color) 
          }
       }
     }
    x
   }
 )
```